# Overhead of an If statement inside cursor loop vs a cursor select

Tags: if-statement, plsql, oracle11g, cursor

suppose I have a procedure that takes in a siteId and empId
which makes the primary key (siteId emp.site_id%TYPE, empId  emp.emp_id%TYPE)
and I'm trying to create an xml clob, I have method called createParent() which creates a parent node, another method called put_child_node, which takes in a parentNode, child element  name, and child element value, however the name and the attribute are taken from a join on two tables. see code:

```
DECLARE 
cursor has_emp_attribute
select 1
from emp_attribute 
where site_id = siteId
and emp_id = empId; <-- quick select

cursor get_emp_attributes
select an.name, ea.attribute_value
from attribute_name an, emp_attribute ea
where an.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
and   ea.site_id = siteId
and   ea.emp_id = empId;

hasAttribute boolean;
parentNode xmldom.domnode;
BEGIN
  hasAttribute := false
  for has_emp_attribute_rec in has_emp_attribute
  loop
    hasAttribute := true;
    parentNode = createParentNode();
    exit;
  end loop;
  if (hasAttribute) then
    for get_emp_rec in get_emp_attributes
        loop
           put_child_node(parentNode, get_emp_rec.name, get_emp_rec.attribute_value);
        end loop;
  end if;
END;
```

If instead I used an if statement to check if we have records inside the second cursor, and create the parentNode in there would this be a better solutions:

```
cursor get_emp_attributes
select an.name, ea.attribute_value
from attribute_name an, emp_attribute ea
where an.attribute_id = ea.attribute_id
and   ea.site_id = siteId
and   ea.emp_id = empId;

hasAttribute boolean;
parentNode xmldom.domnode
BEGIN
  hasAttribute := false
  for get_emp_rec in get_emp_attributes
        loop
           if(hasAttribute = false) then
           parentNode := createParentNode();
               hasAttribute := true;
           end if;
           put_child_node(parentNode, get_emp_rec.name, get_emp_rec.attribute_value);
        end loop;
 END;
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you are creating only one child node in one call than second way is efficient because of less number of cursor and loop. Just make sure that your cursor query fetches the child node for that particular parent.

Comment: That is true if there was only one child node, but there could be many child nodes created.

Comment: if the child node belongs to same parent than also it will work fine.Overall this block will take a parent and will create all the nodes as child which will be fetched in cursor